# Google Protocol Buffers - 64Bit Vs2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, protocol-buffers

I was trying to build Google Protocol 64bit in Vs2010 but I am getting tons of linker and other errors. I downloaded protobuf-2.4.1.zip and went to "vsprojects" folder and then opened the sln file in VS2010 in 64bit architecture. Any solutions on how I can build this ?These were the errors.

```
Error   2   error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    757 1   gtest
Error   5   error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    761 1   gtest
Error   8   error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    769 1   gtest
Error   11  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    773 1   gtest
Error   14  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    781 1   gtest
Error   17  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    785 1   gtest
Error   20  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    793 1   gtest
Error   23  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    797 1   gtest
Error   26  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    805 1   gtest
Error   29  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    809 1   gtest
Error   32  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    817 1   gtest
Error   35  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    821 1   gtest
Error   38  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    829 1   gtest
Error   41  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    833 1   gtest
Error   44  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    841 1   gtest
Error   47  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    845 1   gtest
Error   50  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    853 1   gtest
Error   53  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    857 1   gtest
Error   56  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    865 1   gtest
Error   59  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    869 1   gtest
Error   62  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    876 1   gtest
Error   65  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    882 1   gtest
Error   69  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    757 1   gtest
Error   72  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    761 1   gtest
Error   75  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    769 1   gtest
Error   78  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    773 1   gtest
Error   81  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    781 1   gtest
Error   84  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    785 1   gtest
Error   87  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    793 1   gtest
Error   90  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    797 1   gtest
Error   93  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    805 1   gtest
Error   96  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    809 1   gtest
Error   99  error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    817 1   gtest
Error   102 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    821 1   gtest
Error   105 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    829 1   gtest
Error   108 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    833 1   gtest
Error   111 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    841 1   gtest
Error   114 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    845 1   gtest
Error   117 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    853 1   gtest
Error   120 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    857 1   gtest
Error   123 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    865 1   gtest
Error   126 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    869 1   gtest
Error   129 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    876 1   gtest
Error   132 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    882 1   gtest
Error   136 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    757 1   gtest
Error   139 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    761 1   gtest
Error   142 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    769 1   gtest
Error   145 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    773 1   gtest
Error   148 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    781 1   gtest
Error   151 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    785 1   gtest
Error   154 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    793 1   gtest
Error   157 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    797 1   gtest
Error   160 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    805 1   gtest
Error   163 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    809 1   gtest
Error   166 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    817 1   gtest
Error   169 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    821 1   gtest
Error   172 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest

\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h   829 1   gtest
    Error   175 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    833 1   gtest
    Error   178 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    841 1   gtest
    Error   181 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    845 1   gtest
    Error   184 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    853 1   gtest
    Error   187 error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::tuple_element'  c:\users\Adam\downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h    857 1   gtest
 2.4.1\gtest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-tuple.h   745 1   test_plugin
    Error   471 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\Adm\Downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\vsprojects\Debug\libprotobuf.lib' C:\Users\Adam\Downloads\protobuf-2.4.1\protobuf-2.4.1\vsprojects\LINK   protoc
    Error   482 error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 9009. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets   151 6   lite-test
    Error   542 error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 9009. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets   151 6   tests
```

Comment: Any more information on your errors?  Saying "it doesn't work" doesn't give much to go on.

Comment: "Tons of linker and other errors"... you'll need to provide at least a representative sample of these errors.

Comment: I find it somewhat ironic that you didn't google this. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/protobuf/CxMtjNrFZ2U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors are in `gtest` project, `libprotobuf` should comiple and link fine. If you need to change protobuf library and run tests on it, try downloading [gtest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) framework separately, I think old version is bundled with protobuf, new one should build fine with VS2010.